# Prove that $\color{black}{a\sqrt{b+c}+b\sqrt{c+a}+c\sqrt{a+b}\le \sqrt{a+b+c+2} }$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> **Problem.** Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying $ab+bc+ca=1.$ Prove that$$\color{black}{a\sqrt{b+c}+b\sqrt{c+a}+c\sqrt{a+b}\le \sqrt{a+b+c+2}.  }$$
> Source: JK.

---

I checked that equality holds at $abc=0.$

Indeed, when $abc=0:$ it's obviously true $b\sqrt{c}+c\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}=\sqrt{b+c+2}.$

I've tried to use CBS inequality without success.

I used as $$\sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{b+c}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a}.\sqrt{ab+ac}\le \sqrt{2(a+b+c)}\le \sqrt{a+b+c+2},$$which implies that the original inequality is true when $\sqrt{3}\le a+b+c\le 2.$

We need to prove in remain case $a+b+c\ge 2.$ I've just done it so far.

How can I continue my idea? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof.**

We can divide the original inequality into $2$ cases

$abc=0:$ it's obviously true since $b\sqrt{c}+c\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}=\sqrt{b+c+2}.$

$abc>0:$ by using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality$$LHS=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a^2(b+c)}{a+ab+ac}\cdot (a+ab+ac)}\le \sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab+ac}{1+b+c}\cdot(a+b+c+2)}.$$
Thus, it's sufficient to prove $$\frac{ab+ac}{1+b+c}+\frac{bc+ab}{1+a+c}+\frac{cb+ac}{1+b+a}\le 1,$$or
$$\color{black}{\frac{b+c+bc}{1+b+c}+\frac{c+a+ca}{1+a+c}+\frac{a+b+ab}{1+b+a}\ge 2}.$$
It's equivalent to
$$\sum_{cyc}\left[(b+c+bc)(2+2a+b+a^2+c)\right]\ge 2(a+b+1)(b+c+1)(c+a+1),$$
or
$$6(a+b+c)+6+\sum_{cyc}(b+c)^2+abc(a+b+c)\ge 2(4+3a+3b+3c+a^2+b^2+c^2-abc),$$
or
$$\color{black}{\iff abc(a+b+c+2)\ge 0.}$$
The last inequality is obvious. Hence, the proof is done.

Answer (score 2):

**Proof.** We use the so-called isolated fudging.

The desired inequality is written as
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} a\sqrt{\frac{b + c}{a + b + c + 2}} \le 1$$
or
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left(a\sqrt{\frac{b + c}{a + b + c + 2}} - \frac{a + a(b + c)}{a + b + c + 2}\right) \le 0 \tag{1}$$
where we use $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{a + a(b + c)}{a + b + c + 2} = \frac{a + b + c + 2(ab + bc + ca)}{a + b + c + 2} = 1$.

Note that
$$\left(\frac{a + a(b + c)}{a + b + c + 2}\right)^2 - a^2\cdot \frac{b + c}{a + b + c + 2}
= \frac{a^2(1 - ab - ac)}{(a + b + c + 2)^2} \ge 0.$$
Thus, (1) is true.

We are done.

Comment: That's NICE! [+1]

Comment: I found a proof based on the fact. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(a^2b+a^2c+2ab\sqrt{(a+c)(b+c)}\right)\leq a+b+c+2$$ or
$$a+b+c-3abc+2\sum_{cyc}ab\sqrt{c^2+1}\leq a+b+c+2$$ or
$$4\sum_{cyc}\left(a^2b^2c^2+a^2b^2+2a^2bc\sqrt{c^2+1)(b^2+1)}\right)\leq4+12abc+9a^2b^2c^2$$ or
$$3a^2b^2c^2+4-8abc(a+b+c)+8\sum_{cyc}a^2bc\sqrt{(c^2+1)(b^2+1)}\leq12abc+4$$ or
$$3abc+8\sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{(c^2+1)(b^2+1)}\leq12+8(a+b+c)$$ or
$$64\sum_{cyc}\left(a^2b^2c^2+2a^2b^2+a^2+2ab(c^2+1)\sqrt{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)}\right)\leq(8(a+b+c)-3abc+12)^2$$or
$$192a^2b^2c^2-256abc(a+b+c)+64(a+b+c)^2+128\prod_{cyc}(a+b)\sum_{cyc}ab\sqrt{c^2+1}\leq$$
$$\leq64(a+b+c)^2+9a^2b^2c^2+144-48abc(a+b+c)+192(a+b+c)-72abc,$$
which after using C-S gives
$$183a^2b^2c^2+72abc+128(a+b+c-abc)\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}ab\sum_{cyc}ab(c^2+1)}\leq$$
$$\leq144+192(a+b+c)+208abc(a+b+c)$$ or
$$183a^2b^2c^2+72abc+128(a+b+c-abc)\sqrt{abc(a+b+c)+1}\leq$$
$$\leq144+192(a+b+c)+208abc(a+b+c),$$ which is true because even $$192(a+b+c)\geq128(a+b+c-abc)\sqrt{abc(a+b+c)+1}$$ is true.

Can you end it now?

Comment: I think $uvw$ helps very well.

Comment: @TATA box I think it's trivial without $uvw$.